# How to use jQuery's .not and :contains in case of multiple values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$("table[id=" + tblName + "] tr").not(":contains('" + val + "')").hide();
```

This code will hide all `TR`s not containing "val".

I have "val1" and "val2" in my code. I wish to hide `TR`s *not* containing both "val1" and "val2"

How do I do that?

^>^ Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logically an AND exclusion:

```
$("table[id=" + tblName + "] tr").not(":contains('" + val1 + "'):contains('" + val2 + "')").hide()
```

Logically an OR exclusion:

```
$("table[id=" + tblName + "] tr").not(":contains('" + val + "')").not(":contains('" + val2 + "')").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, Bro.. I tired, it look work. but at this time, I want not Contains VAL1 "AND" VAL2. If run your code. It hide all TR not Contains VAL1 "OR" VAL2. Let me try 1 more times, and I will reply u back. Thanks help, bro

Comment: I was actually looking for the OR and grabbed it out of your edit =)